# Are field extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3})$ the same thing?

Tags: galois-extensions

As the title, I came across a question to compute the Galois group for $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))$ and I'm getting a bit confused about how to approach it.

Comment: Yes, those two fields are the same by definition. This is a quadratic extension, hence the galois group is obviously the group with two elements.

Comment: They are the same, just like the polynomial rings $K[X][Y]$ and $K[X,Y]$ are the same.

Comment: @Bernard I'd argue that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3})$ are the same subfields of $\mathbb R$ while $K[X][Y]$ and $K[X,Y]$ are only canonically isomorphic. But that is certainly a little pedantic and off-topic for this question.

Comment: @Christoph: I only wanted to explain the intuition  behind ‘the same thing’.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ that contains $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt{2}$. That is, it is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt{2}$.
- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ that contains $\mathbb Q$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. That is, it is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.
- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ that contains $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $\sqrt{3}$. That is, it is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Do you see how the last two items define the same subfield of $\mathbb R$?